# AngularJS 1.0.7 Service synchronized call

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an AngularJS 1.0.7 webapp. In my service.js I have a `SearcherService` service which is trying to call `CurrencyService` service synchronously, but something is not working.

```
.factory('SearcherService', function(CurrencyService, LocationService) {
    return {
        var currency = LocationService.getCurrency(); 
        if (currency == undefined) {
            var currency = CurrencyService.getCurrency();
            // do more thing after currency is got
        }
    };
})
.factory('CurrencyService', function(LocationService, Currency) {
    return {
        getCurrency: function() {
            Currency.query(function success(result) {
                var currencies = result;
                LocationService.setCurrency(currency[0]);                       
                return currency[0];         
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**UPDATE**
Actually there is not an error stacktrace. But my intended behavior is to get currency value from CurrencyService.getCurrency before continue executing the // do more things. I don´t know why I have other services calls that doesn´t continue until the service method call is completely executed but I don´t see the difference. Please, also see my Currency service.
I would like to do something like this. But this is not working. It´s never getting inside the callback function.

```
var currency = LocationService.getCurrency(); 
if (currency == undefined) {
    CurrencyService.getCurrency().then(function(result) {
        currency = result;
        // do more thigs
    });                                                         
}
```

See also my Currency service:

```
.factory('Currency', 

      function($resource, SERVER_URL){          
        var currencies =
         $resource('http://' + SERVER_URL +'/:action', {action:'currencies'}, {       
            query: {method:'GET', isArray: true},
            getConversionRate: {method:'GET', params:{action:'getConversionRate'}, isArray: false}
         });        
         return currencies;           
      }
  )
```

Comment: Can you give us anything more than "something is not working"? A stack trace? Intended behavior and actual behavior?

Comment: doesn't look synchronous to me...what does `Currency.query()` look like?